# How to Change action bar setBackgrounddrawable Color in Android Studio using R.Color in Java File?

Tags: java, android, colors, background, r.java-file

I want to Change color of Action Bar using Java code in Android studio,

I have color.xml file for color codes

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getColor(R.color.colorVelocity)));   **//<<Error NullPointerException**
```

Tell me how to resolve this issue, as I want to use R.color I don't want to use color.parsecolor ("#hexcolor");

Comment: try this : setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.holo_light_green))

Comment: No its not working, not resolving

Comment: setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.MainColor))); you can try this also

Comment: Are you setting the actionBar before calling `getSupportActionBar()` ??

Comment: @Himani let me try this one

Comment: getResources().getColor(R.color.MainColor) is showing Strike bar on getcolor()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a null pointer exception issue. I'm not sure where you're calling the getSupportActionBar() from (that will give me a bit more context as to why) but you should always check for null when you call it. So change your code to...

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
if (actionBar != null) {
  actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorVelocity))); 
}
```

[EDIT]

If you don't want to use the deprecated getResources().getColor() method, use this instead...

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
if (actionBar != null) {
  actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorVelocity)));
}
```

Comment: action bar object is working well, but 
setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getColor(R.color.colorVelocity)));

is not working

Comment: Just realised that calling getColor requires API 23. Try calling getResources().getColor() instead. I'll edit the code above.

Comment: let me try this one

Comment: Hi Umair, I'm not sure what you mean by strike?

Comment: I think that strike bar is for the deprecated method.

Comment: yeah so what can i do now?

Comment: you can still use that deprecated method, it'll still work

Comment: If you don't want to use the deprecated method, you can use: actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorVelocity)));

Comment: Thanks it is working 
' actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorVelocity))); '

Thanks @Chris-ward 
now edit your answer

Answer (score 2):

Try these lines to change color of Actionbar.

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#000000")));
```

Comment: as i mentioned i don't want to use this

Answer (score 0):

Using this code you'll be able to use `Color.parseColor()` but with color from resources.

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
if (actionBar != null) {
  actionBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#"+Integer.toHexString(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorVelocity))); 
}
```

Comment: let me try this one

Comment: wait let me try this one

Comment: what is context here? Context is red "can't resolve"

Comment: if you are inside an activity you don't need to write context

Comment: i'm inside Main Activity but by removing contaxt it is still showing error. red under line

Comment: Then you don't need to wrote context, just write getResources()